# How to capture page to PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

**Ps.My English isn't well.**

I want to export HTML page to PDF. 
I try to use jsPDF, isn't work,try PhantomJS it use alot of spec (3xxMb).
I don't know .
Whatever it can make my HTML page to PDF?
Please tell me.

This is my table:

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain what your use case is? Are you planning to automate a process, or allow users of your site to export the current view as a PDF? (for example)

Comment: One option is also [PDFReactor](http://www.pdfreactor.com/).